# I am receiving a fatal error with class stripe/stripe not found on my website checkout page after installing Stripe API, what could be causing this?

Tags: php, magento, stripe-payments, fatal-error

I have installed Stripe API using php composer on my website which is currently using Magento 2.2. I ran "composer require stripe/stripe-php", which installed all the correct files.

However, on the checkout page on my website, I am receiving an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Stripe\Stripe' not found in /home/collamod/public_html/app/code/Webkul/MpStripe/Model/PaymentMethod.php:174 Stack trace: #0 /home/collamod/public_html/generated/code/Webkul/MpStripe/Model/PaymentMethod/Interceptor.php(24): Webkul\MpStripe\Model\PaymentMethod->initializeStripe('sk_live_hGgIuYd...') #1 /home/collamod/public_html/app/code/Webkul/MpStripe/Model/PaymentMethod.php(164): Webkul\MpStripe\Model\PaymentMethod\Interceptor->initializeStripe('sk_live_hGgIuYd...') #2 /home/collamod/public_html/generated/code/Webkul/MpStripe/Model/PaymentMethod/Interceptor.php(14): Webkul\MpStripe\Model\PaymentMethod->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Model\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\Registry), Object(Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory), Object(Magento\Payment\Helper\Data), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config), Object(Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger), Object(Webkul\MpStripe\Helper\Data), Object(Webkul\Marketplace\Helper\ in /home/collamod/public_html/app/code/Webkul/MpStripe/Model/PaymentMethod.php on line 174
```

My composer.json file has the appropriate lines required:

```
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.1",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "mage2pro/stripe": "*",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^5.7"
},
```

On Line 174 in PaymentMethod.php as the error indicates, the code is:

```
public function initializeStripe($stripeKey = false)
{
    if ($stripeKey) {
        if ($this->getDebugFlag()) {
            \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripeKey);
        } else {
            \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripeKey);
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What could be the reason for this? Any insight would be kindly appreciated! Thank you!

Raymond Z.

Comment: Can you try running `composer show -i` or just `composer show` to see if it was installed successfully?

Comment: I ran composer show and it seems like nothing related to stripe was included in the long list that popped up. Does this mean that it was not installed successfully?

Comment: Try `composer update`

Comment: The fact that it's an "official" modules does not make it bugproof. I had same problems with a french payment module calle Oney. Did you check that the class actually exists and is named after PSR-4 ?

Comment: @BrianGottier I ran it and it did not resolve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: @ChristopheFerreboeuf Sorry I'm a bit of a noob but where would I check for the class' existence and where would I check if it is named after PSR-4? I know that the module is using PSR-4 though.

Answer (score 1):

Please run this command

`composer require stripe/stripe-php`